# How do I keep null and false valued elements in .filter()?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm trying to resolve from a Javascript array everything that is not an number, but look at what it does when the array holds other falsy elements than zero:

```
[false,null, false, true].filter((x)=>x)
```

that returns

```
[true]
```

but I want to keep the falsy elements. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Can you give an example with numbers, and what you are actually expecting as the result? Your description does not make it obvious.

Comment: So, you want to remove everything that is not a number, except falsy values, i.e. `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `''` and `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Then don't rely on falsiness checks, explicitly test for numbers.

```
[false, null, false, true].filter(x => typeof x !== 'number')
```

Comment: That will still remove `null` and `true` and `false` though. The question is weird I guess.

Comment: Yeah I wrote it and then decided I wasn't 100% what the OP actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude all the numbers (not sure I understood you correctly), then you can do:

`[false,null, false, true].filter((x) => !Number.isInteger(x));`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JavaScript has several values that are considered a false value. By sending identity `x => x` all values that are considered false will be filtered away.

You need to supply a function/lambda that returns false when it is a number and true for everything else. eg.

```js
[false, null, false, 5, 5.3, true].filter( x => typeof(x) !== 'number')
; ==> [false,null, false, true]
```